# Java Reflection library that has a function to create NewInstance for any Class with any Constructor

Tags: java, oop, generics, reflection

I am looking for a Java library that provides a function like this,
[invokeConstructor](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L150). (don't want to import clojure.lang)

Comment: @jtahlborn : I wanted to know if there is a standard one in Java that is used. I can always copy that code but I think using a standard library is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

apache commons-beanutils:

```
Object args[] = ...;
Class<?> argTypes[] = ...;
Object obj = ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(clazz, args, argTypes);
Object obj = ConstructorUtils.invokeExactConstructor(clazz, args, argTypes);
```

The big difference between "invokeConstructor" and "invokeExactConstructor" is that the former  will find a type assignment compatible constuctor, while the latter will match only the exact argument types you've supplied.   (see java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom)

Comment: yeah, it's a typo.  will fix it.